# jQuery Script in user control, runs for only one instance of that control on the page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an CollapsiblePanelExtender control with gridview which i put inside a user control.

I add the following script to the end of the User control to smooth out the animation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        $find(("<%= CPE.ClientID %>"))._animation._fps = 35;
        $find(("<%= CPE.ClientID %>"))._animation._duration = 0.5;
    }

</script>
```

When i run the page only the 2nd accordion gets smoothed out, the first one is default sluggishness.

The following is the runtime scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        $find(("MainContent_AccordionGV1_CPE"))._animation._fps = 35;
        $find(("MainContent_AccordionGV1_CPE"))._animation._duration = 0.5;
    }

</script>
```

.
.
.
.

```
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        $find(("MainContent_AccordionGV2_CPE"))._animation._fps = 35;
        $find(("MainContent_AccordionGV2_CPE"))._animation._duration = 0.5;
    }

</script>
```

So it should be working according to this.
Any idea why it isn't?

Thanks.

Addition:

I tried manually adding it to the Page instead of the User Control, same behaviour.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function pageLoad(sender, args) {
            $find(('<%= AccordionGV1.FindControl("CPE").ClientID %>'))._animation._fps = 35;
            $find(('<%= AccordionGV1.FindControl("CPE").ClientID %>'))._animation._duration = 0.5;
        }
</script>
```

works
when i add the same lines but for AccordionGV2..the first one stops working.

Makes me think it is a bigger problem than that.

Comment: What is calling your pageLoad function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use this script in UserControl instead:

```
(function () {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(pageLoadedHandler);

    function pageLoadedHandler() {
        $find(("<%= CPE.ClientID %>"))._animation._fps = 35;
        $find(("<%= CPE.ClientID %>"))._animation._duration = 0.5;
    }
})();
```

This way each user control won't override `pageLoad` function defined before and will use own handler for pageLoaded event

Comment: worked VERY well, thanks a lot..
Only problem is I don't really understand why/how it works :)

Comment: It's an auto-executed anonymous function that adds each instance's pageLoadedHandler to the list of things to run when the page loads.

Comment: In addition to @antmx comment, the `pageLoadedHandler` function doesn't overrides previously registered handlers as it nested in self-evaluated anonymous function scope. So each user control register own handler for `pageLoaded` handler of PageRequestManager

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd pageLoad() function is overriding the 1st. Try giving each instance's pageLoad() a unique name, e.g. suffix it with he UserControl's ClientID:

```
pageLoad_<%=this.ClientID%>()
```

Comment: very probable, didn't think of that *duh*.

Comment: they did override each other.
renaming the function to anything other than pageLoad makes it not load automatically though.

Comment: `pageLoad` is function used by naming convention by MicrosoftAjax library when page rendered. So if you'll use different name this function won't be called

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy - agreed, it's better to use the auto-executed anonymous function to add each instance's pageLoadedHandler to the list of things to run when the page loads.